# Parse Error On input on two functions - Haskell

Tags: haskell, parse-error

In this segment of code my compiler throws parse error on input for the line

```
tuple_up parsed_int list_of_points
```

and

```
let new_point = ((fst last_point), (snd last_point) + 1)
```

From previous posts on these errors they recommended checking the preceding whitespace, which I did. All the lines are correctly indented with tabs. It seems this problem has to do with things after the first "let" line?

```hs
go_up :: [String] -> [(Int, Int)]
go_up string_path list_of_points =
    let parsed_int = parse_current string_path
    tuple_up parsed_int list_of_points

tuple_up :: Int -> [String] -> [(Int, Int)]

tuple_up 0 list_of_points = list_of_points
tuple_up increment list_of_points =
    let last_point = tail list_of_points
    let new_point = ((fst last_point), (snd last_point) + 1)
    let new_list_of_points = list_of_points ++ new_point
    tuple_up (increment - 1) new_list_of_points
```

Comment: It should be `let ... in ...`, only in a `do` block you do not write an `in`

Answer (score 3):

Outside of a `do`, `let` works a bit differently than inside. In particular:

1. It requires an `in`. The correct syntax is `let x = y in z`
2. It is possible to bind multiple values, but each one has to either have a corresponding `in` or come without a separate `let`

Applying these points to your code:

```
go_up :: [String] -> [(Int, Int)]
go_up string_path list_of_points =
    let parsed_int = parse_current string_path
    in tuple_up parsed_int list_of_points

tuple_up :: Int -> [String] -> [(Int, Int)]

tuple_up 0 list_of_points = list_of_points
tuple_up increment list_of_points =
    let last_point = tail list_of_points
        new_point = ((fst last_point), (snd last_point) + 1)
        new_list_of_points = list_of_points ++ new_point
    in tuple_up (increment - 1) new_list_of_points
```

After this you're going to get another error, because `last_point` is not a point, but a list (look at the definition of `tail`), which means you can't apply `fst` and `snd` to it.

And after that you're going to get yet another error, because your type signature says that `list_of_points` is a list of  `String`, but then you're trying to treat its elements like tuples.